# Adding extra step to ASP.NET MVC authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 website running using standard forms authentication.

However I need to add an extra step to the user's login process. Once the user has been authenticated we look up whether or not they have access to multiple offices. If they do we need to show them a list of offices and they must choose one.

This is a mandatory step and they cannot be considered logged on until they do it.

Do we need to create our own authentication or should I add a check to a BaseController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the implementation of the built-in authentication:

```
public class OfficeSelectionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var result = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if (result)
        {
            if (IsOfficeSelected())
            {
                return true;
            }

            httpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute("OfficeSelection Route");
            httpContext.Response.Flush();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool IsOfficeSelected()
    {
        //office selection check
    }
}
```

Then you need to use this filter instead of the default one:

```
[OfficeSelectionAuthorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //action methods
}
```

Comment: Following from this I now need to understand how to Stash the selected office in the logged on user's Identity. I've asked the question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100679/adding-extra-data-to-auth-cookie-after-login-mvc-5. Any thoughts?